# Configuration of Jaxb2Marshaller with many XSD files doesn't work [JAVA 12]

Tags: xml, spring, xsd, jaxb, marshalling

I'm trying to create an automatic XML marshelling validation in spring with redefinition of `HttpMessageConverter`. I wrote a script which adds a `Jaxb2Marshaller` Bean as `MessagConverter` in the `WebMvcConfigurer` converter list. But I have a problem with my `Jaxb2Marshaller` configuration when I used many XSD files as schemas. Spring recognizes only objects related to the first XSD file. This is my marshaller code :

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan("nbf.toto.core.xml");
    marshaller.setSchemas(new ClassPathResource("/xsd/file1.xsd"), new ClassPathResource("/xsd/file2.xsd"));
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    map.put(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
    marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(map);

    return marshaller;
}
```

There is a sample code, how to set many xsds as Schemas for XML Validation? I'm using Java 12, Srping 5 and Jaxb 2.3.2

Comment: Don't set schema's, just packages to scan which should cover **all** the packages containing JAXB generated classes. Also make sure that when generating classes they don't overwrite each other (especially the `ObjectFactory`) when trying to shoehorn everything into a single package.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but when I removed schemas, the xml validation is disabled and I have some wrong tags that are mapped into class. My goal is to send Bad request when the controller received an xml with wrong information like bad tags, value types...

Comment: Then include the schema's but as stated you also need all the packages in packages to scan and make sure that things don't get overwritten during object generation in JAXB.

Comment: The nbf.toto.core.xml is the main package of classes generated by JaxB. And i paid attention on tags name, so i have got generated classes with different name.

Comment: The problem is using multipl xsds, the `ObjectFactory` will be overwritten for the different xsd (unless they are processed in one go I guess). Another thing to try is to use `classesToBeBound` instead of `packagesToScan` put the top level classes in there.

Comment: Hi, i made the change that you said about ClassesToBound. Now the check is available but the Marshaller only consider the first XSD in parameter. For example, when i change file2.xsd by file1.xsd in marshaller.setSchemas(), i can check the file2 XML. But when i do the reverse, i have an Error : Marshaller doesn't recognise my XML rootTag.

Comment: Validation in JAXB, especially with multiple schemas, can be tricky. The schemas are consulted in the order they are defined in. This is a limitation in JAXB, so creating 1 marshaller to rule them all (basically) isn't going to work. You would need multiple for each schema, if you want validation that is. Even if you define multiple XSD files eventually they will become a singe `Schema` (there is no way to set multiple schemas on a JAXB marshaller!).

Comment: You are right, because when I looked into the JaxbMarshaller class, I found that the setSchemas takes many objects in parameter but merge all in on object. And during the validation, this object is used. I found another solution for my problem and it makes the job very well. Thank @M.Deinum very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many search days, I found that Jaxb2Marshaller doesn't allow XSD validation on XML with different root tags. So if you have two different XSD related to different entities, and you add those XSD to Jaxb2Marshaller bean for validation, Jaxb2Marshaller will only consider the first XSD file. And the XML related to the second XSD, will throw an exception.

So for my goal, i have created a XML Marshaller util, to convert XML to the given XSD Class with validation. And in my controller, i receive the XML as String in @RequestBody. After i convert this String to the given XSD class with my util. This is an example of methode that i used :

```
public static Object convertXmlToClass(final String xmlContent, final Class classe, final String xsdFileName) throws Exception {

    final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(classe);
    final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

    try {
        final ClassPathResource xsdFile = new ClassPathResource("/xsd/" + xsdFileName + ".xsd");
        final SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsdFile.getInputStream()));
        unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e.getStackTrace());
        throw new Wy6Exception("An Error occured during the XML convertion.");
    }

    Object result = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));

    return result;
}
```